# "Fatal error: Call to a member function getSummaryHtml() on a non-object in Abstract.php on line 319"

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, review

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSummaryHtml() on a non-object in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php on line 319

```
/**
 * Get product reviews summary
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param bool $templateType
 * @param bool $displayIfNoReviews
 * @return string
 */

public function getReviewsSummaryHtml(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $templateType = false, $displayIfNoReviews = false)
{
    if ($this->_initReviewsHelperBlock()) {
        return $this->_reviewsHelperBlock->getSummaryHtml($product, $templateType, $displayIfNoReviews);
    }

    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$this->_reviewsHelperBlock should be initiated with Mage_Review_Block_Helper Please check in this file

```
protected function _initReviewsHelperBlock()
{
    if (!$this->_reviewsHelperBlock) {
        if (!Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Review')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->_reviewsHelperBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper');
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```